# jQuery + Webkit +... switching between CSS3 transitions/transforms and javascript automatically?

Tags: jquery, iphone, animation, ipad, transformation

it may sound a weird question not easy also to explain:

Jquery works flawless on any desktop web browser but as you may have already noticed is pretty cluncky on iphone/ipad/ipod because is not hardware accelerated as the webkit transforms are...the latter are very smooth...but they work only on apple products.

my question is if do you know if there is someome out there that already build a system that automatically convert/translate jquery commands into html5 commands..based on detection of the browser...

the point is bascially to have something that works flawless everywhere ...

Comment: Hey Frank, they are CSS3 transitions/transforms, not HTML5 transitions/transforms. You might want to update your title and tags so you get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this but I've written a plugin that will automatically enhance certain jQuery animations to the CSS3 transition equivalent. You don't need to change any of your code to do so.

It makes iPad/iPhone development really easy as it will use the hardware accelerated transitions when it detects them.

Just drop the plugin in and enjoy: http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/

Comment: I wish it were possible to hug people over the internet.

Comment: great job....but way to buggy to be used and unfortunately it actually stop working when using animate on scrollTop... but a good start